# How to change the default 30s for the google authenticator

Tags: google-authenticator

Google Authenticator defaults to refresh the verification code every 30s. I want to change it to refresh the verification code every 24 hours. How can I achieve this?
In addition, I read the source code and found a value. After modifying it to 86400 (24h), the installation does not take effect after the compilation is completed.  In source code; \src\google-authenticator.c  793lines.
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd8WK.png)

Answer (score 1):

RFC 6238 [states that:](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238#:%7E:text=We%20RECOMMEND%20a%20default%20time%2Dstep%20size%20of%2030%20seconds.%20%20This%20default%0A%20%20%20value%20of%2030%20seconds%20is%20selected%20as%20a%20balance%20between%20security%20and%0A%20%20%20usability.)

> We RECOMMEND a default time-step size of 30 seconds.  This default
> value of 30 seconds is selected as a balance between security and
> usability.

I'm not aware of any way to change this value for Google Authenticator, and 24h seems very long.

Comment: Thank you, because sometimes the device time is more than 1 hour different from the standard time. Our device security requirements are not so high. So 24 hours is more appropriate.

Comment: the standard time or device time doesn't matter cos google uses epoch time which is the same for the entire planet at any given time.